# Merge SQL to Exclude Duplicate Records So Merge 2nd time Doesn't Fail

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have three tables and only one that I directly control and am doing a `MERGE` between them. See my abbreviated but working example here ([sqlfiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1f39c/32)).

I am doing a `MERGE` between table 1 and Table 2 to Table 3. Table 1 has duplicate data which the `MERGE` (erroneously) can handle on the first run (insert) but fails with this message on the second run (update).

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once.

My question is, can the `MERGE` be written to either use an `EXCEPT` such as

```
SELECT AdFull FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE AdFull IS NOT NULL
EXCEPT
   SELECT AdFull FROM   [dbo].[Users]
   WHERE  AdFull IS NOT NULL
   GROUP BY AdFull
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

or a different Join to only show users that are not duplicated? Or even a way to select a specific one of the duplicates?

---

### Answered Questions

1. `MERGE` is a working Insert due to the nature of Fiddle. But due (AFAIK) to the stateless nature of fiddle one never sees the error in Fiddle on a second run, because a *merge* never happens with the data, only inserts.
2. Ignore Rows: Actually I would eventually like to use an individual duplicate row via divining of one based on a condition. The actual data table I am dealing with away from the fiddle example has more columns and it would be nice to maybe select a specific row in a duplicate set due to a specific condition.
3. The example doesn't bare it out, but yes the duplicates are due to the computed AdFull column. Think of a system adding a temp employee, that user gets a row. Then the temp employee gets hired on as fulltime, keeps the ad account but then gets another row in the user table. *Yes I know it shouldn't happen.* So that is how a duplicate comes about.
4. (Duplicate values Table 3) Table three is a result table that can be cleaned out for any duplicates to start this process afresh.

Comment: Is that Fiddle for the `MERGE` that works or the `MERGE` that doesn't?

Comment: Also do you really want to completely ignore rows that have duplicates? Are these true duplicates meaning all columns of the row are the same or do they just all have the same `AdFull`?

Comment: Cool do you have a column that you can use to showthat someone has been hired on Full Time?

Comment: @Zane add a `date` column such as "StartedOn" as not null, and each record added has a different started on date. The most recent date would be the decider.

Comment: Okay last question is there also a duplicate of this information in table 3?

Comment: @Zane, Table 3 could be `Truncated` so one doesn't have to worry about duplicate values in that table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `MERGE` statement can you do something similar this?

```
MERGE INTO [dbo].Table3  AS T3
USING
(
SELECT 
    AdFull,
    MAX(StartedOn)  
FROM [dbo].Table2 AS [ad]
GROUP BY AdFull
  ) AS T2
ON (T2.AdFull = T3.AdFull)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE blah

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT blah
```

Using the `MAX` aggregate with a `GROUP BY` should give you only the information from when the temp was hired on. Then if the AdFull matches you can simply `UPDATE Table3` with the most recent information and if there is no match then `INSERT` a new row.

UPDATE: If I fail to mention that `MERGE` should be used with [caution](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/) I will take flak from @AaronBertrand.

Comment: I am finding that there are other _anomalies_ in the real data which are giving duplicates, but your advice in general is sound to divine a record. Thanks.